# App, tool or widget to collect documents or BLOBs of different formats

Tags: document-management, knowledge-organization

I use Slack, email, Whatsapp, Skype, MS-Teams etc and it makes little or no difference which app or account I have been using, but rather I would like to mark some content in Slack or mark a (part of an ) email or chat message, tag it with "work", "database" or similar tags and then copy it to a storage where I can collect content of many different formats but they are all "documents" or BLOBs. It could also be a hyperlink or some random content, but I would like some way to structure content coming from many different sources from several different accounts of mine.

It will very well happen that I receive a chat message on Whatsapp with my private account with information that is revelant for my work account somewhere else, then I would like some app to which I can copy many kinds of content for retrieval later.

There is already notes app for example Evernote and Samsung Note but I did not find a platform-independent way to do this.

Ideally I would like an app similar to bitwarden but for content and this app should be possible to run with many different platforms (Linux, Android, Windows 10...).